# Email open tracking on mu4e

Tags: mu4e

On Nylas N1 email client it is possible to see if receiving person has opened your email. They call this feature *open tracking*. Is it possible to configure emacs email client mu4e to have this feature?

Answer (score 2):

E-mail tracking is performed by embedding a link to server in a mail, as described [here](https://support.nylas.com/hc/en-us/articles/226411088-How-does-Nylas-perform-Open-Tracking-) for Nylas.  This requires server-side infrastructure which mu4e doesn't provide.

(It is also not very reliable, since it requires the recipient to enable display of remote images.)